# asp.net mvc url on .uk but not on .com?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

hi i have put this together this morning for a friend using MVC

he has .com and .co.uk

now my urls are /artwork/{project name}

but on .com i dont get /artwork/{project name} in the address bar, even though it still works

here is the url

turncoatandrun  dot  co  dot uk
and dot com

have never really noticed this before is it a bug ????

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .com domain is just pointing (but hiding it) to .co.uk

If you hover over your links, and watch the status field of your browser, you'll notice that it shows the .co.uk domain.

My guess is that .com is just using a www-forward. Check out the html of the .com domain, and you'll notice that it just includes .co.uk with a frame :-)

Comment: lol im a dic* i set up that domain too, thats what happens when u work on a weekend too LOL   talk about shot it.